# Is there a programmatic approach to prevent Safari from storing my website in the Frequently Visited Pages section?

Tags: safari, preview

I've noticed that when my website appears in Safari's Frequently Visited Sites preview, it displays sensitive data from my site. Is there a way to customize the thumbnail or control what is displayed in the preview to prevent sensitive data from being shown?

For those not familiar, I am referring to this section.
[Frequently visited section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cILj5.png)

What I have tried so far.

1 - I tried this answer: [Safari Top Sites Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055418/safari-top-sites-preview), but the answer is from 2012 and this method: `window.navigator.loadPurpose` don't even exist on Safari.

2 - I thought, maybe I could tell safari to don't include my website in the frequently visited.
Unfortunately I couldn't find any method for a website developer to prevent their site from appearing in Safari's Frequently Visited Sites section.

3 - My second thought was that if I can't hide it, at least we could modify the image on the preview.
But there, I also couldn't find a direct way to customize the appearance of your website in Safari's Frequently Visited Sites preview.

From what I found out, Safari automatically generates these previews using a snapshot of your site, and there's no specific meta tag or method to modify this behavior directly.

Any suggestion about other approaches? I could take? my Website is a Single Page Application.

Thank you